# $n \geqslant m$ given restriction of a linear transformation on all dim $m$ subspace injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given $n \times m$ matrix $A, B$ in $\operatorname{Mat}_{n \times m}(F)$.
If for all invertible matrix $C \in \operatorname{GL}_{n}(F)$. we have the linear map
$$
x \longmapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}
A \\
C B
\end{array}\right) x
$$
an injetive map.
Is that $n \geqslant m$ ?

If on the other hand, we have
$$
x \mapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}
A \\
B D
\end{array} \right)x
$$
an injective map for all $D \in \operatorname{GL}_{m}(F)$.
Is that $n \geqslant m$ in this case?

Geometrically I think it's true (and for $m=1$ it's easy). But I cannot prove the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, one can multiply on the left by $\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & C^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$, and so the map is invertible for all invertible $C$ if and only if it's invertible when $C=I$. Thus it is necessary that $2n\ge m$ but not necessary that $n\ge m$. (For a simple example take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.)

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a very nice argument.

Comment: Is there any hint for the second half part please?

Comment: Got it now…  The second half is true and at least one of A or B has rank m

Answer (score 0):

Some detail for the second half as a note:

Say the canonical form of $A$ and $B$ are $P^{-1} I_r Q$ and $S^{-1} I_s T$, respectively.

Then
$$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
A \\
B
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
P^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & S^{-1}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
I_r \\
I_s
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ll}
Q & 0 \\
0 & T
\end{array}\right)
$$
If rank of both $I_r$ and $I_s$ is less then $m$, then
$$
x \longmapsto\left(\begin{array}{l}
I_r \\
I_s
\end{array}\right) x
$$
is not injective. It gives $C=T^{-1} Q$ such that
$$
x \mapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}
A \\
B C
\end{array}\right) x
$$
not injective. Hence $m=\max (\operatorname{rank} A, \operatorname{rank}(B)) \leq n$.